# How to load a apply jQuery function upon appending a <div> via Ajax?

Tags: html, css, jquery

I'm appending a `<div>` via Ajax. There are jQuery functions and CSS to be applied to that `<div>` after getting appended dynamically via Ajax. The `<div>` gets appended correctly but the jQuery functions and CSS does not get loads for that `<div>`. How do I do it?

**AJAX CODE**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data : { 'widgets_list' : widgets_list },
            success: function(result){
                console.log(widgets_list);
                $("#column1").append(result);     // div gets appended.
                }
            });
```

**view.py**

```
HTMLstr += "<div class='portlet'><div class='portlet-header'>Live Graph</div>" + \
                    "<div class='portlet-content' id='live_graph' style='height: 270px  margin: 0 auto'>" + \
                    "</div></div>"

return HttpResponse(HTMLstr)
```

The `jQuery functions` which needed to applies are:-

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column",
      handle: ".portlet-header"
    });

    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
      .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

 });

and 1 more jQuery function.
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
              body { min-width: 520px; }
              .column { width: 170px; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px;}
              .portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
              .portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
              .portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
              .portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; max-height: 270px;}
              .ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
              .ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**

**HTML**

```
<div class="column span4" id="column1">
                <div class="portlet">
                    <div class="portlet-header">Line Chart</div>
                    <div class="portlet-content" id="basic_line" style="height: 270px"></div>
                </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Function**

```
$(function () { // I replaced this line with $("#portlet").on('click', '#live_graph',function() {.... But it didnt work!!
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#live_graph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

I want this highchart to be in the portlet-content, but I'm unable to. Where am I going wrong?

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Can `ready` be an event?

Comment: At what stage does your ajax request run, is it on click from another function, or on page load?

Comment: There's a dialog box,upon confirming the Ajax request is sent.

Comment: Then that is how you should trigger your function to work. At the mo it is assigning it but because it is not present nothing happens.

Comment: I didnt get you. How should I trigger my functions and CSS? Can you please provide with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to break it down by the functions you listed.

## Function 1

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
     connectWith: ".column",
     handle: ".portlet-header"
 });
```

This is very specific to jQueryUI, but in order for Function 1 to work,  you need to use http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh . Since some of the items in your sortable are loaded later you need to referesh the sortable to recognize these items.

So you will have code like

```
success: function(result){
   // div gets appended.
   $("#column1").append(result);     
    // refresh sortable items now that markup is appended to columns
   $( ".column ).sortable( "refresh" );
}
```

## Function 2

```
   $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
      .find( ".portlet-content" );
```

Is there a reason why this markup is not generated in **view.py** , since view.py is already generating dynamic markup. If you prefer to do this in jQuery, make you sure you invoke the function after appending the result.

## Function 3

```
   $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });
```

Instead of needing to call this function each time the element is created, there is a concept known as **event delegation**. The premise of [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is that  **Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time**. But in order to apply event delegation, **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to***
From your ajax call it looks like the function is `"#column_1"` already exists by the time the result is appended.

An example of event delegation is :

```
  // This tells #column_1 that if a descendant element matches the selector
  // '.portlet-header .ui-icon' then invoke the function

  $('#column_1').on('click', '.portlet-header .ui-icon' ).,function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks !!!Works like a charm.
I have a query. I'm trying to apply the other jQuery function dynamically to the div wth class `.portlet-content` and id `live_graph` with parent div `.portlet`. This is what I've done and I'm not able to get the correct o/p.
`$(".portlet").on('load', '#live_graph',function() {`

Comment: @AnthonyS- Kindly give your valuable suggesstions. Please do the needful. Thanks

Comment: What do you want your load event to do?